# Passing in a callback with an action dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm wondering if the following code snippet violates any [Redux guidelines](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions), particularly with regards to putting non-serializable values in state or actions.

From my understanding, it does not violate any guidelines, since it’s not an action called within an action. Instead, the code is passing in a callback that has an action dispatch in it, so it would be safe.

Are there any other Redux guidelines that it might violate?

```
const handleActivationChange = (): void => {
          if (data.active) {
              dispatch(userActions.handleConfirmation({
                message: '"Are you sure you want to perform this action?"'
                onConfirm: () => { dispatch(userActions.updateActivation(data, !data.active)) }
              }));
          } else {
              dispatch(userActions.updateActivation(data, !data.active));
          }
      };
```

Comment: When did you call the onConfirm ?

Comment: This snippet of code violate redux rules you are right

Comment: onConfirm is called in another component - it controls a "submit" button.

Can you clarify exactly why it's a violation?

Comment: State must be serializable if you put a function inside of it, this break this rule

Comment: Can you show the code of the button who is calling this function ?